# Is there a way to get the average over X minutes while also averaging based on groups in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, mean

I'm trying to get the average temperature over a certain amount of time (ex. 30 min) based on the groupings in the code below `group_by(Type, Rainfall, datetime)`. I'm thinking this is something I'll need to average before averaging based on groups but maybe there is a way...
I'm not even sure how to go about attempting this so any help would be lovely!

```
df_Temps1.means <- df_Temps1 %>% 
  group_by(Type, Rainfall, datetime) %>% 
  summarise(Temp_mean=mean(temperature, na.rm=TRUE), n=n(), sd=sd(temperature, na.rm=TRUE), se=sd/sqrt(n))
df_Temps1.means$se<-as.numeric(df_Temps1.means$se)
df_Temps1.means$Temp_mean<-as.numeric(df_Temps1.means$Temp_mean)
df_Temps1.means
```

This is a portion of my dataframe I'm working with:
[image: This is a portion of my dataframe]

Comment: Can you run `dput()` on a portion of your data and share the output so we can work with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can most definitely do it,

##### First convert 'datetime' to a POSIXct object for time-based calculations:

```
df_Temps1$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df_Temps1$datetime)
```

##### Then Calculate the 30-minute intervals:

```
df_Temps1 <- df_Temps1 %>% 
mutate(interval = cut(datetime, breaks = "30 min"))
```

##### Then group by 'Type' , 'Rainfall' and 'interval', then calculate the mean temperature:

```
df_Temps1.means <- df_Temps1 %>% 
group_by(Type, interval) %>%
summarise(Temp_mean = mean(temperature, na.rm = TRUE))
```